# IBM x3250 M4 server is runnig slow

Tags: ibm-server

I have a IBM x-3250 M-4 server installed windows server 2008.
The complete installation took 4 hrs.
And system is running very slow.
Anyone can help me please.....

Comment: Is one of your disks failing?

Comment: No i have changed a new Segate 7200rpm hdd. Still its getting slow..Can you tell me how to update the BISO.

Comment: Cant help you there  Im guessing you meant BIOS, and thats a goid thought. Relatedly, is the disk <= 2tb? A long time back I had an HP that had painfully slow IO as the firmware did not support advanced format disks. (but this might not be a disk issue at all)

Comment: I am trying to start the server from 5 days. I tested different O.S. Still not working. So i am thinking to update the firmware once..